# cross site data acess in sharepoint online

Tags: cross-site, sharepoint-online, office365-apps

In SharePoint online I have 2 site collections created by default, the root site collection and the people host, with -my, I believe both of them are created from different web applications.

I am trying to access a file from my site host sitecollection and that file is residing in the root site collection , I am accessing this using JSOM, however, I am unable to fetch that file.

Any workarounds/resolutions to fetch site across site collections which seem to have different web applications using client side?

Answer (score 1):

You are querying another domain, and cross-domain JavaScript calls are blocked for security reasons. You need to pass execCrossDomainRequest as a parameter when getting SP.RequestExecutor.js to execute your query with the JavaScript cross-domain library as described on MSDN:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179927.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396